# Possible to convert result of Drupal db_query to PHP array?

Tags: drupal

In Drupal, I can execute a SQL as follows:

```
$query_object = db_query("SELECT * FROM {nodes}");
```

If I know the query returns only a single result (so only 1 row and 1 column), I can directly fetch it with:

```
$result = db_result($query_object);
```

If I got multiple results, I need to loop through them with something like:

```
$rows[] = array();
while (($row = db_fetch_object($query_object) != FALSE) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do that? Is there a way that I can transfer all results into an array with a single statement? Or isn't that working, because db_result returns a cursor-like object, where you can only fetch a single row each time?

Comment: Never seen any function that does what your want in Drupal, but it pretty easy to create a wrapper function that does the while() loop for you.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is another Drupal database API, which is not cursor based. But it seems it doesn't exist.

Comment: [db_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_result/6) is not used when the query returns a single row, but when the query just selects a field. In your example, I would not use that function with `SELECT * FROM {nodes} …`, but with `SELECT nid FROM {nodes} …`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not in Drupal 6.

In Drupal 7, there are fetch methods that can help to avoid loops like that. From http://drupal.org/node/310072:

```
<?php
// Retrieve all records into an indexed array of stdClass objects.
$result->fetchAll();

// Retrieve all records into an associative array keyed by the field in the result specified.
$result->fetchAllAssoc($field);

// Retrieve a 2-column result set as an associative array of field 1 => field 2.
$result->fetchAllKeyed();
// You can also specify which two fields to use by specifying the column numbers for each field
$result->fetchAllKeyed(0,2); // would be field 0 => field 2
$result->fetchAllKeyed(1,0); // would be field 1 => field 0

// Retrieve a 1-column result set as one single array.
$result->fetchCol();
// Column number can be specified otherwise defaults to first column
$result->fetchCol($column_index);
?>
```

Comment: no simple way to get an array of arrays rather than an array of objects?

Comment: See the linked page, "Note that fetchAll() and fetchAllAssoc() will by default fetch using whatever fetch mode was set on the query (numeric array, associative array, or object). That can be modified by passing in a new fetch mode constant. For fetchAll(), it is the first parameter. For fetchAllAssoc(), it is the second parameter."

Answer (score 20):

In Drupal 7, you can also use:

```
db_query('QUERY')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 2):

I do always something like this ( just a simple exemple) :

```
  $query = db_query("SELECT nid
        FROM {from}
        WHERE blallala
        ", 
     $tab_arg
    );
    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    $output=t('no result')
   } else
    {
foreach($query as $result)
 {
 $tab_res[]=$result;
 }
foreach($tab_res as $res)
 {
 $output.=$res->nid;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One can also use [`db_fetch_array($result)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_fetch_array/6), where `$result =`[`db_query($queryString)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6). As explained from the Drupal documentation:

> [It returns] ...an associative array representing the next row of the result, or
>   FALSE. The keys of this object are the names of the table fields
>   selected by the query, and the values are the field values for this
>   result row.

Comment: Yes and no, it only returns the next result in the result set as array, but not all results in one big array :-)